# What is unique about veal and how can I take advantage of this in my preparation?

Tags: veal

First off, I'm talking about what they call Rose Veal here, not the crate Veal which has given the meat such a bad name.

So, I've tried a few recipes: a roast, a stew and some breadcrumbed escalopes. The escalopes were fantastic, but I can't honestly say any of it was better than the equivalent dish made with beef, or pork where a milder flavour was desired.

But, the veal wasn't exactly cheap, so am I missing something?  I'd sort of expected something a bit more special if I'm paying a premium for it.

Are there some specific preparation methods and/or pairings which show the meat off better? What is it people enjoy so much about veal and how can I accentuate that quality?

Comment: Hey robin, recipe requests are considered off-topic here but I think the question you are trying to ask is how to bring out veals flavor which would probably be better as a community wiki anyway. You can see some examples of these here: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/search?q=community+wiki . You can also see what is considered on or off topic in the faq at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Veal is naturally tender, with a mild flavor.

I'm currently living in an area where I don't know where to even get veal easily, but we'd have it for special occassions at my great-grandmother's house growing up.

Think if it like the cow equivalent of lamb.  Anything that comes out well in lamb (shank, rib chops, shish-kabab, etc) works well.  My mom would also get a 'meatloaf mix' of beef, veal and pork growing up to use in meatballs and meatloaf, which I've since learned that the fats melt at different temperatures, which makes for a more juicy meatloaf.

I don't know that I've had enough veal to comment on what people enjoy so much about it.  (Although, I love osso bucco, and I don't know how a grown-cow equivalent would come out).

I also don't know that veal was always considered the "delicacy" that it is today -- male cows (bulls) can get agressive when get older, so they were culled at a younger age.  As I don't see veal for sale, and I don't see fields full of bulls, I can only assume it's either exported to other countries, or that it's used in products like dog food or processed products where people won't get obsessed with ethical issues so much.  (and if that's the case, it's not being sold for high value).

Comment: thanks, I've seen a few references to Osso Bucco so will maybe make that my next experiment. I was starting to think the historic place for Veal might have been as a relatively cheap meat seen as a side line to milk producion but hadn't got as far as looking at any old recipes yet to try and confirm/deny this. Some more investigation to be done I think. Thanks again.